# PHP How to assign eval(0 to variable

Tags: php, variables, eval

```
<?php  
    $xs = eval("if ('1' == '0')
                echo 'never';
            else
                echo 'always';");

    //echo $xs;
```

This code returns 'always' but i don't want it.
I need to take this variable elsewhere.

Sorry for bad english.

**EDIT:**

PEOPLE!!!!!!!This sample code. I know that eval() in this case is not needed, but the code in my other projects will be. I need to what eval() returns were entered into a variable. "

Comment: Hint: the code does not return anything. It only echoes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a simple way to get the result:

```
<?php  
ob_start();
eval("if ('1' == '0')
            echo 'never';
        else
            echo 'always';");
$xs = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
//echo $xs;
```

To get the return value of `eval()` you'll need to return something inside the evaluated code, e.g.:

```
$xs = eval("return '1' == '0' ? 'never' : 'always';");
echo $xs; // echoes 'always'
```

Comment: you don't need no eval in that case ^^

Comment: I assume he has some legitimate use for `eval()`, and he's just posting some fake code to solve the problem of capturing the output of the eval'ed code to a variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
$xs = ('1' == '0') ? 'never' : 'always';
```

Answer (score 1):

this code makes no sense and eval sucks :-)

try something like this:

```
$xs = '1' == '0' ? 'never' : 'always';
echo $xs;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$xs = ('1' == '0') ? 'never' : 'always';
```

This is an alternative structure that you can use in string too, given you get parenthesis around it :)

Answer (score 0):

Dont use eval !

```
function test()
{
    return '1' == '0' ? 'never' : 'always';;
}

echo test();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a very good reason to use eval you can use one of its fiends `create_function` instead.

```
$x2 = create_function( '$a', 'echo $a == 1 ? "yes" : "no";' );
$x2( 1 ); // echos 'yes'
```